# JSON parser that can handle large input (2 GB)?

Tags: c++, c, json

So far, I've tried (without success):

- [QJsonDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qjsondocument.html) – "document too large" (looks like the max size is artificially capped at `1 << 27` bytes)
- [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/property_tree.html) – takes up 30 GB RAM and then segfaults
- [libjson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibJSON) – takes up a few gigs of RAM and then segfaults

I'm gonna try [yajl](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) next, but Json.NET handles this without any issues so I'm not sure why it should be such a big problem in C++.

Comment: Obviously at least one problem is simply the amount of heap required to generate the representation.  Depending on the types of objects the parser spits out it could generate output amounting to somewhere between 10x and 100x the size of the input.  Whichever parser uses the most parsimonious objects will probably be the winner.

Comment: Heh, parsimonious parser.

Comment: I would work VERY hard at reducing the size of the actual data, instead of trying to find one that copes. You are not going to please anyone by shipping gigabytes across the network, even if you can run it pretty quickly locally, if you start distributing the data, network will be hugely limiting factor.

Comment: There really isn't much I can do about the data size, but it will never need to be distributed over a network. (It is downloaded from S3 during the bootstrap stage of an Elastic MapReduce job, but that only takes a few seconds.)

Comment: You might want to try a destructive parser (rapidjson is one, I think), but my guess is that you're getting a segfault because the library is failing to allocate more memory. There's only so much you can do about that.

Comment: I assume it goes without saying that you need a 64-bit operating environment for this.  A 32-bit environment has a 2-4 GB limit.

Comment: Do you really need a representation? How about an event-driven approach (akin SAX-stly for XML, e.g. reads a stream, and produces a stream in a different format)

Comment: @dauphic Thanks for the rapidjson recommendation! I'll try that if yajl doesn't work (looks like yajl is also event-driven, so it should work).

Comment: @Hot Licks Yep, the nodes are all 64-bit with more RAM than I should need. (As mentioned, I've been testing on a system with >30 GB.)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Nope, definitely don't need a representation; I hadn't even thought to look for parsers advertising that detail, thanks!

Comment: Yep, for normal-sized JSON payloads event-driven schemes are a lot more trouble than they're worth, but for this sort of thing it may be a necessary evil.

Comment: Ryan, I've some experience in implementing JSON parser; when you can be more explicit about the generated output, then we can probably provide a possible solution. – CouchDeveloper 6 mins ago   edit

Comment: Well, I just need some way to successfully extract the data and insert it into a boost::interprocess::map for the rest of my code to use; after the map is set up, everything related to the JSON parser is thrown out, so the interface to the parsing library doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've developed a JSON representation which internally uses standard conforming containers. The containers are specified via template policies. The JSON container can use custom allocators (according the scoped allocator model). This JSON container can be used as the representation generator of a JSON parser. The development state is beta and not tested on non Mac OS X systems, though. The public API is Obj-C, but the internals are all C++11. If you have more questions, please head over to:[JPJson](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson). Examine classes: `json::value` and `json::parser`.

Comment: Do you need to extract ALL the data, or only a portion of it.  If you need ALL the data (and all at one time) then probably a standard parser (using "parsimonious" objects) is your best bet.  (You can look for one that processes a "steam" vs a byte string, to save a little on storage.)  If you only need some of the data then event-driven or some such may be better.  (I actually posted the code for a simple Qt JSON parser here maybe 2 years back.  It was about 250 lines of code.)

Comment: (Make that 500 lines.  The serializer was about 250.  Search for QvJson.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I ended up having to solve a few tangentially related problems before I could be sure my solution worked, but I finally got my code working (posted as an answer). JPJson would have been awesome (efficiently parsing JSON of arbitrary size being exactly what I needed), but unfortunately I don't have access to an OS X system. Yeah, I do need access to all of the data at once. Boost ptree and JsonCpp (which I tried after posting this) both used streams but still blew up. Re: QvJson, QJsonDocument was actually added to Qt in version 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not proud of my solution, but I ended up using some regex to split my data up into top-level key-value pairs (each one being only a few MB), then just parsed each one of those pairs with Qt's JSON parser and passed them into my original code.

Yajl would have been exactly what I needed for something like this, but I went with the ugly regex hack because:

1. Fitting my logic into [Yajl's callback structure](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/yajl-2.0.1/structyajl__callbacks.html) would have involved rewriting enough of my code to be a pain, and this is just for a one-off MapReduce job so the code itself doesn't matter long-term anyway.
2. The data set is controlled by me and guaranteed to always work with my regex.
3. For various reasons, adding dependencies to Elastic MapReduce deployments is a bigger hassle than it should be (and static Qt compilation is buggy), so for the sake of not doing more work than necessary I'm inclined to keep dependencies to a minimum.
4. This still works and performs well (both time-wise and memory-wise).

Note that the regex I used happens to work for my data specifically because the top-level keys (and only the top level keys) are integers; my code below is *not* a general solution, and I wouldn't ever advise a similar approach over a SAX-style parser where reasons #1 and #2 above don't apply.

Also note that this solution is extra gross (splitting and manipulating JSON strings before parsing + special cases for the start and end of the data) because my original expression that captured the entire key-value pairs broke down when one of the pairs happened to exceed [PCRE's backtracking limit](https://serverfault.com/a/408272/142441) (it's incredibly annoying in this case that that's even a thing, especially since it's not configurable through either QRegularExpression or grep).

---

Anyway, here's the code; I am deeply ashamed:

```
QFile file( argv[1] );
file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );
QTextStream textStream( &file );

QString jsonKey;
QString jsonString;
QRegularExpression jsonRegex( "\"-?\\d+\":" );

bool atEnd = false;


while( atEnd == false )
{
    QString regexMatch  = jsonRegex.match
    (
        jsonString.append( textStream.read(1000000) )
    ).captured();

    bool isRegexMatched = regexMatch.isEmpty() == false;

    if( isRegexMatched == false )
    {
        atEnd = textStream.atEnd();
    }

    if( atEnd || (jsonKey.isEmpty() == false && isRegexMatched) )
    {
        QString jsonObjectString;

        if( atEnd == false )
        {
            QStringList regexMatchSplit = jsonString.split( regexMatch );

            jsonObjectString = regexMatchSplit[0]
                .prepend( jsonKey )
                .prepend( LEFT_BRACE )
            ;

            jsonObjectString = jsonObjectString
                .left( jsonObjectString.size() - 1 )
                .append( RIGHT_BRACE )
            ;

            jsonKey    = regexMatch;
            jsonString = regexMatchSplit[1];
        }
        else
        {
            jsonObjectString = jsonString
                .prepend( jsonKey )
                .prepend( LEFT_BRACE )
            ;
        }

        QJsonObject jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson
        (
            jsonObjectString.toUtf8()
        ).object();

        QString key = jsonObject.keys()[0];



        ... process data and store in boost::interprocess::map ...


    }
    else if( isRegexMatched )
    {
        jsonKey    = regexMatch;
        jsonString = jsonString.split( regexMatch )[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: A SAX style parser can theoretically handle very large data files. It would probably be fairly easy to make a splitter using it if you felt like cleaning up the code. I haven't tried it but this one claims to have a sax json parser: https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/YasserAsmi/jvar.  I have tested it with a large database (SF street data or something, which was around 2GB).   It was quite fast.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the recommendation! I'll have to test it out on my data set just out of curiosity, but I ended up using an ugly regex-based hack to just split my data up into top-level key-value pairs (~3 MB each) and pass each one in to Qt's JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently finished (probably still a bit beta) such a library:

```
https://github.com/matiu2/json--11
```

If you use the json_class .. it'll load it all into memory, which is probably not what you want.

But you can parse it sequentially by writing your own 'mapper'.

The included mapper, iterates through the JSON, mapping the input to JSON classes:

```
https://github.com/matiu2/json--11/blob/master/src/mapper.hpp
```

You could write your own that does whatever you want with the data, and feed a file stream into it, so as not to load the whole lot into memory.

So as an example to get you started, this just outputs the json data in some random format, but doesn't fill up the memory any (completely untested nor compiled):

```
#include "parser.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **) {

  std::ifstream file("hugeJSONFile.hpp");
  std::istream_iterator<char> input(file);

  auto parser = json::Parser(input);
  using Parser = decltype(parser);
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  switch (parser.getNextType()) {
  case Parser::null:
    parser.readNull();
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
    return;
  case Parser::boolean:
    bool val = parser.readBoolean();
    cout << "Bool: " << val << endl;
  case Parser::array:
    parser.consumeOneValue();
    cout << "Array: ..." << endl;
  case Parser::object:
    parser.consumeOneValue();
    cout << "Map: ..." << endl;
  case Parser::number: {
    double val = parser.readNumber<double>();
    cout << "number: " << val << endl;
  }
  case Parser::string: {
    std::string val = parser.readString();
    cout << "string: " << val << endl;
  }
  case Parser::HIT_END:
  case Parser::ERROR:
  default:
    // Should never get here
    throw std::logic_error("Unexpected error while parsing JSON");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

## Addendum

Originally I had planned for this library to never copy any data. eg. read a string just gave you a start and end iterator to the string data in the input, but because we actually need to decode the strings, I found that methodology too impractical.

This library automatically converts \u0000 codes in JSON to utf8 encoding in standard strings.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with records you can for example format your json and use the newline as a separator between objects, then parse each line separately eg:

```
"records": [
{ "someprop": "value", "someobj": { .....   } ... },
.
.
.
```

or:

```
"myobj": {
"someprop": { "someobj": {}, ... },
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem with Qt's 5.12 JSON support. Fortunately starting with Qt 5.15 (64 Bit) reading of large JSON files (I tested 1GB files) works flawlessly.